# WordPress post details

Tags: wordpress, post

I have WordPress page in which post titles of a single category are showed. When the user clicks any of the post a new tab should open and show the details of the post on which the user clicked how will I do this.

Comment: find the link in the code and give it a blank target.

Comment: Give the product titles a hyperlink like

<a href="http://steve.mirealux.com/product/2nd-test-simple-subscription/" target="_blank">2nd test simple subscription</a> 

target="_blank" will make your link open in new tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just simple the page where you found the list of post title is your "`archive`" or "`category`" page check where it's from coming. in that template give the link to your title like `<a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $post->ID ) ?>">` which link you your single.php file in that change accordingly.

Comment: i didn't get the last part of single.php can u explain it bcuz i am new to wordpress

Comment: when you click on this link it will call your single.php file will call and where you can design and change view of post. for more detail read this artical
https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#single-post

Comment: i have one more question that i have featured image set to the post how will i display that on the main page

Comment: if you call within page then just pass this function <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID 'full' ); ?>  For more info https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_post_thumbnail